# Python import of GdkPixBuf says "introspection typelib not found"

Tags: python, import, raspberry-pi, gdkpixbuf

I have some imports:

```
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk, GdkPixBuf
```

An error (maybe 2) is raised:

```
WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2158, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'DynamicImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "camerapython.py", line 10, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gdk, GdkPixBuf
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 53, in find_module
    'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name GdkPixBuf, introspection typelib not found
```

What I have noticed is that in the importer.py of gi, repository.enumerate_versions(namespace) returns [] for GdkPixBuf (and so raises the error).

Other imports returns something:

```
Gtk : ['3.0']
GObject : ['2.0', '2.0']
GLib : ['2.0', '2.0']
Atk : ['1.0', '1.0']
Gdk : ['3.0', '3.0']
cairo : ['1.0', '1.0']
```

If needed, my dist is Raspbian (Raspberry Pi 3).

Comment: Did you try to install gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

You're importing Pixbuf wrong, it should be

```
from gi.repository import Gdk, GdkPixbuf
```